# Error de launching en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Cada vez que ejecuto mi app me da este error en Android Studio y no entiendo por que, espero su ayuda

> 08/12 15:09:06: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-A207M.
> $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.basededatossqlite/com.example.basededatossqlite.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.basededatossqlite/com.example.basededatossqlite.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.basededatossqlite/.MainActivity }
> Error type 3
> Error: Activity class {com.example.basededatossqlite/com.example.basededatossqlite.MainActivity} does not exist.

> Error while Launching activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es:

> Activity class
> {com.example.basededatossqlite/com.example.basededatossqlite.MainActivity}
> does not exist.

Aunque indica que la Activity no existe en realidad no puede ser ese el problema, hay varias causas de este problema primeramente te sugiero desinstalar la app, pero ve a `settings` > `apps` , ahí ubicala y selecciona `"Uninstall for all users"`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]